# Python in GNOME code base

Tags: gnome, python, development

Is Python present in the Gnome code base? If so, how is it involved?

**Note**:

My question concerns the core GNOME Desktop Environment only (e.g. **`nautilus`**, **`gnome-session`**, **`NetworkManager`**) and any underlying App or library.

Answer (score 3):

Currently there are 3 modulesets for GNOME 3:

1. GNOME Core dependencies (e.g GLib, GTK+, D-Bus); In a sense, this can can be called GNOME platform.
2. GNOME Core (e.g. Nautilus, gnome-power-manager, gnome-session)
3. [GNOME Featured Apps](https://live.gnome.org/TwoPointNinetyone/FeaturedApps) (e.g. Anjuta, Evolution, gedit)

Here's modules that depend on Python, directly or not:

- [EOG](http://projects.gnome.org/eog/), the image viewer is part of GNOME Core. For GNOME 2, there is gnome-panel and gnome-applets, both which are to be replaced by 'shinier' GNOME 3 tech.
- dbus-python, which provides a Python interface to D-Bus, is part of GNOME Platform.
- There's a number of modules in GNOME Featured Apps, which not only depend on Python, but also PyGTK.

I'm likely missing some more. But the point is that GNOME sees heavy usage of Python. I think it's the second most used language after C for the above modulesets. Either Vala or C# is third, not sure. Maybe I must fire up [sloccount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/) on my checkouts :)