# How can I run a command for a list of packages?

Tags: shell, debian, package-management

I tried to install Gnome 3 on Debian Testing following [this explanation](http://raphaelhertzog.com/2011/06/16/installing-gnome-3-on-debian-6-0-squeeze-no-sorry/). However, this didn't work and left me without any graphical user interface.

At the moment I try to fix that and I realised there is a long list of packages marked as manually installed. I stored a (line-break separated) list of the packages that – in my opinion – should be marked as auto installed (nearly all of them).

Now I want to run `apt-mark auto` for this list.

How do I do that?

P.S.: I also would appreciate if somebody tells me that this is not a good idea (if it isn't).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use xargs:

```
 cat /path/to/file | xargs apt-mark auto
```

This should work if there is one package name per line in the text file `/path/to/file`.

Another option would be to use a for loop:

```
 for pkg in `cat /path/to/file`; do apt-mark auto $pkg; done
```

The second way might be useful if you have a similar problem where the command can't be called with a list of parameters but you have to call it once for each parameter you have. But in your case it's not that elegant of course… :)

Btw I assume that you are using bash.

**Note:** On my system `apt-mark --help` says:

```
Usage: apt-mark [options] {markauto|unmarkauto} packages...
```

And also:

```
apt-mark is deprecated, use apt-get markauto/unmarkauto.
```

Comment: With `xargs`, you can just write `</path/to/file xargs apt-mark auto`; and it'll cope with any whitespace separation between package names, not necessarily newlines (`xargs` has quoting issues but Debian package names don't contain any problematic character so it's ok here). An even simpler method is `apt-mark auto $(cat /path/to/file)` (which, again, works without requiring any special precaution because package names don't contain special characters).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to dump your list of files into `apt-mark auto` one at a time.  This pseudo-code should get you started:

```
while read pkgname; do apt-mark auto $pkgname; done <list_of_packages
```

Comment: Why you calling this pseudo-code? It does work.

Comment: True, it does. There's just no sanity checking, error reporting, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Run the following script with `python scriptname.py list-of-packages.txt` [as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3063):

```python
import subprocess
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
with open(filename) as f:
    packages = f.read()
    packages = packages.split()
    packages = " ".join(packages)
    cmd = "apt-mark auto " + packages
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

I expect that this wouldn't be a problem since [having GNOME implies that you already have Python installed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8849/python-in-gnome-code-base/8857#8857).

Comment: You've just reinvented xargs, minus its quoting issues but they're not a problem here.

Comment: I was sure there was a better way of doing things. It just so happens I was the first to answer so I thought something sub-optimal is better than nothing :)